# Formating Results from Scaper

Tags: python

I'm getting an error while trying to format a simple amazon scraper.
I'm trying to scrape amazon then create a tweet using the twitter API. After scraping Amazon I want to format the results, so I can pull the results to my twitter API.

While trying to format I get an error

**ERROR:**

```
  File "/Users/user/Coding/TestRequests/amazonscraper.py", line 32, in <module>
    deals = tvprices[0].replace("'title'", "Product: ")
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

**CODE:**

````
from requests_html import HTMLSession


urls = ['https://amzn.to/3PUatLc']

def getPrice(url):
    s = HTMLSession()
    r = s.get(url)
    r.html.render(sleep=1)
    try:
        product = {
            'title': r.html.xpath('//*[@id="productTitle"]', first=True).text,
            'price': r.html.xpath('//*[@id="corePriceDisplay_desktop_feature_div"]/div[1]/span[2]/span[1]', first=True).text,
            'discount': r.html.xpath('//*[@id="corePriceDisplay_desktop_feature_div"]/div[1]/span[1]', first=True).text.replace('-', '')
        }
        print(product)
    except:
        product = {
            'title': r.html.xpath('//*[@id="productTitle"]', first=True).text,
            'price': 'item unavailable'
        }
        print(product)
    return product



tvprices = []
for url in urls:
    tvprices.append(getPrice(url))

deals = tvprices[0].replace("'title'", "Product: ")

print(deals)```
````

Any help would be appreciated. I'm just learning so this might be way more simple than I'm thinking.

Thanks all!

Comment: The error is self explanatory!! Dict has no method replace. Are you trying to replace the key name? Then, do this `tvprices[0]["Product"] = tvprices[0].pop("title")`

Answer (score 1):

You can't replace Dictionary keys. If you'd really like to do something along the similar lines, you could delete the existing key and put another key as `Product:` . However, that's not the best resort.

You might want to build another List with the formatted data.

```py
formatted_deals: List[str] = []

for tvprice in tvprices:
  formatted_deals.append(f"Product: {tvprice['title']}")
```

Comment: Ok I think im on the right path.

`File "/Users/user/Coding/TestRequests/amazonscraper.py", line 32, in <module>
    formatted_deals: List[str] = []
NameError: name 'List' is not defined`

Im getting this error now. What do I define the List as. I'm just learning Python.

Comment: I added a type, `List[str]`, for the variable `formatted_deals` to convey that it's a list of strings. You could remove `: List[str]` if you're not familiar with typing for now. It's optional. You could read more about typing here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html.